# How can I use lookarounds in with multiple values upon which they operate

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have the following Regex

```
^(?'a'month[s]?|day[s]?|year[s]?)*\s*(?'b'month[s]?|day[s]?|year[s]?)*(?<!\k<a>|\k<a>s)$
```

And my input is:

```
days day
```

My goal is to match `day month`, `year day` etc.

But not to match `days day`, `day days`, `days days` etc.

So it does the jo okay BUT, it matches `days day` which is incorrect.

I was thinking if in my lookbehind I could somehow say that if the value that it operates upon(in this case `day` OR the value that it operates upon concatenation with an `s`) and the expression does not equal the value of capturing group `a` and capturing group `a` concatenated with `s` , them this would solve the problem

Comment: Use `^(?'a'month|day|year)s?\s*(?!\k<a>)(?'b'month|day|year)s?$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a lookahead to restrict the the second group pattern:

```
^(?'a'month|day|year)s?\s*(?!\k<a>)(?'b'month|day|year)s?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wrqiAw/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?'a'month|day|year)` - Group `a`: `month`, `day` or `year`
- `s?` - an optional `s` letter
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(?!\k<a>)` - the text immediately on the right cannot be the text captured in Group `a`
- `(?'b'month|day|year)s?` - Group `b` - `month`, `day` or `year` - and then an optional `s` char
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 1):

There is no requirement for any of your sections of regex to match.
And your named groups are quantified. I wonder if you intended this.

The below regexs' assume *only* two forms of *`days`* cannot stand.

This regex assumes you require one of each *a* and *b* groups.

```
^(?'a'(?:month|day|year)s?)\s*(?'b'(?:month|day|year)s?)(?<!days?\s*days?)$
```

https://regex101.com/r/qRKLzs/1

This regex assumes both *a* and *b* groups are optional.

```
^(?'a'(?:month|day|year)s?)?\s*(?'b'(?:month|day|year)s?)?(?<!days?\s*days?)$
```

https://regex101.com/r/0DkGSa/1

Note that if these regex are used in a *multiline option* context
there should be consideration to changing `\s` to a horizontal whitespace meaning.

Like this

```
^(?'a'(?:month|day|year)s?)?[^\S\r\n]*(?'b'(?:month|day|year)s?)?(?<!days?[^\S\r\n]*days?)$
```

https://regex101.com/r/YgZI40/1